# Flutter: How can i tap on item(product) and go to detail?

Tags: flutter, dart, socket.io, flutter-dependencies

I'm using a socket io. I could listed all the items and made them clickable but when I try to go to detail it returns null. How can I go to detail of the item that I clicked?

I tr

```
return Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 
                                                                       5),
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      InkWell( onTap: (){

                                          MyNavigator.goToDetail(context);

                                        },
                                       child: Row(
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            Expanded(
                                              flex: 40,
                                              child: Container(
                                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 
                                                                 2, left: 3,),
                                                child: Column(
                                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                                  CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                  children: <Widget>[
                                                    Text(

                                          x["symbols"].elementAt(index).name,
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          color: 
                                                        Colors.black54,
                                                          fontSize: 18,
                                                          fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.bold),
                                                    ),
                                                    Padding(
                                                      padding:
                                                      EdgeInsets.all(1),
                                                    ),
                                                    Text(
                                                      x["symbols"]
                                                          .elementAt(index)
                                                          .lastUpdate,
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          color:
                                                          Color(0xFF96979A),
                                                          fontSize: 13),
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
```

Comment: It seems like you are not passing data. check this https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data

Comment: thanks it worked  but i reply too late :)